# Haproxy Sockjs Websocket loadbalancing and RabbitMQ loadbalancing in same config

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy, spring-websocket, sockjs, spring-rabbit

I am looking for a haproxy (HAProxy version 1.5.18) configuration which will allow websocket loadbalancing as well as RabbitMQ load balancing. I have tried many options but none seem to work, below is my haproxy config file:

```
    global
        log         127.0.0.1 local2

        chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
        pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
        maxconn     4000
        user        haproxy
        group       haproxy
        daemon

        stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    defaults
        mode                    http
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        option                  dontlognull
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
        option                  redispatch
        retries                 3
        timeout http-request    15s
        timeout queue           1m
        timeout connect         10s
        timeout client          1m
        timeout server          1m
        timeout http-keep-alive 10s
        timeout check           10s
        maxconn                 3000
        timeout tunnel          3600s

    frontend http_web *:80
        mode http
        default_backend rgw

    backend rgw
        balance roundrobin
        server rgw1 173.36.22.49:8080 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie rgw1 check
        server rgw2 10.42.139.69:8080 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie rgw2 check

    listen stats :9000
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
        stats uri /haproxy_stats  # Stats URI
        stats auth websocketadmin:websocketadmin

    listen ampq
        bind *:61613
        mode tcp
        option clitcpka
        server rabbit1 10.42.6.112:61613 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
        server rabbit2 10.42.6.113:61613 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
        server rabbit3 10.42.6.114:61613 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
        server rabbit4 10.42.6.115:61613 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
```

Haproxy doesn't give any error, it prints the below message, but it doesn't work, i cannot connect to websocket or connect to Rabbitmq. ***But as soon as i remove "listen ampq", everything starts working fine.***

```
    Sep  8 21:00:40 localhost haproxy[3184]: Proxy http_web started.
    Sep  8 21:00:40 localhost haproxy[3184]: Proxy rgw started.
    Sep  8 21:00:40 localhost haproxy[3184]: Proxy stats started.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the port 61613, which was already taken by another process. So i had to change to a new port and add it in the firewall rules and it is working now.